# Python script to generate report of packet drop

Tags: python, networking

Considering a log file which has time stamp ip and other info as below:

```
22:30 1.1.1.2 buffer overflow
22:30 1.1.1.2 drops 10 packets
22:30 1.1.1.3 drops 15 packets
22:35 1.1.1.2 drops 20 packets
```

I want to parse the log and output:

```
1.1.1.2 dropped a total of 30 packets
1.1.1.3 drooped a total of 15 packets
```

I started out as:

```
f = open('log.txt', 'r')
for line in f:
     if 'drops' in line:
     output = line.split()[1:]
     print output[1], output[3]
```

This will give me:

```
1.1.1.2 10
1.1.1.3 15
1.1.1.2 20
```

I'm not sure how to chk for the same ip and then add the packets. 
Can someone help? Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use defaultdict for this purpose

```
from collections import defaultdict

d=defaultdict(int,{})
f = open('a.txt', 'r')
for line in f:
     if 'drops' in line:
         data=line.split()
         d[data[1]]=d.setdefault(data[1], 0)+ int(data[3])
f.close()
print d
```

## output

```
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'1.1.1.2': 30, '1.1.1.3': 15})
```

if defaultdict is overkilling we can just use dict

```
d={}
f = open('a.txt', 'r')
for line in f:
     if 'drops' in line:
         data=line.split()
         d[data[1]]=d.setdefault(data[1], 0)+ int(data[3])
print d
```

Answer (score 2):

```
with open('log.txt', 'r') as f:
    drops = {}
    for line in f:
         if 'drops' in line:
             time, ip, fn, n, packets = line.split()
             drops[ip] = drops.get(ip, 0) + int(n)
for ip, count in drops.items():
    print ip, count
```

This produces the output:

```
1.1.1.2 30
1.1.1.3 15
```

Two items to note about this code:

- This uses python's `with` construct so that you can be sure that the file is closed when it is no longer needed.
- The data is unpacked into variables with meaningful names:

  ```
  time, ip, fn, n, packets = line.split()
  ```

  This makes the line which follows more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Collect all ips like dict key and add packet_lost num as value

```
>>> ip_dict = {}
>>> with open('file.txt') as f:
...     for line in f:
...          if 'drops' in line:
...              output      = line.split()[1:]
...              ip          = output[0]
...              packet_lost = output[2]
...              if not ip_dict.get(ip,{}):
...                 ip_dict[ip] = 0
...              ip_dict[ip] += int(packet_lost)
... 
>>> 
>>> ip_dict
{'1.1.1.2': 30, '1.1.1.3': 15}
```

Then you can interate and format the output

```
>>> for ip, total in ip_dict.iteritems():
...     print '%s dropped a total of %i packets' % (ip,total)
... 
1.1.1.2 dropped a total of 30 packets
1.1.1.3 dropped a total of 15 packets
```